# Change dataframe displayed in pandastable (tkinter widget)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

I am currently working on a GUI that displays pandas dataframes.

I want an `OptionMenu` to select the dataframe from a list and then display it in the pandastable.

My current approach: I have an attribute curTable in my class and I initially fill it with the first dataframe, which is correctly displayed in the pandastable. Then when the value of my `StringVar` connected to my `OptionMenu` changes I call a callback function that changes the attribute and redraw the pandastable.

```
import tkinter as tk
from pandastable import Table, TableModel
import pandas as pd

    class test_gui():

        def __init__(self):
            self.root = tk.Tk()
            LF3 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root, text='Output')
            LF3.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=(4,4), pady=4, sticky="nsew")  

            def tableSelChange(*args):
                df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],['what', 'is', 'this'],[123, 123, 123]], 
                                   columns=['This', 'is', 'a Test'])
                df2 = pd.DataFrame([['bruh', 'this', 'is a gui'],[1235, 1235, 1235],[123, 123, 123]], 
                                    columns=['This', 'is', 'a Test2'])

                if tableSelVar.get() == 'One':
                    print('ONE')
                    self.curTable = df1
                elif tableSelVar.get() == 'Two':
                    print('Two')
                    self.curTable = df2
                #self.dfTbl.redraw()
                #dfTbl.tableChanged()
                dfTbl.redraw()

            tableSelVar = tk.StringVar(LF3)
            tableSelVar.set('No tables available')

            tableSelMenu = tk.OptionMenu(LF3, tableSelVar, 'One', 'Two')
            tableSelMenu.pack()

            df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],['what', 'is', 'this'],[123, 123, 123]], 
                               columns=['This', 'is', 'a Test'])
            df2 = pd.DataFrame([['bruh', 'this', 'is a gui'],[1235, 1235, 1235],[123, 123, 123]], 
                                columns=['This', 'is', 'a Test2'])

            self.curTable = df1

            LLF31 = tk.LabelFrame(LF3, text='Table editor')
            LLF31.pack()
            dfTbl = Table(LLF31, dataframe=self.curTable, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
            dfTbl.show()

            tableSelVar.trace('w', tableSelChange)

            self.root.mainloop()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        t = test_gui()
```

When I select the second dataframe, the pandastable does not change. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I think I have the solution:

I am using TableModel to load in the dataframe and then use the method `updateModel()` of pandastable.

```
def tableSelChange(*args):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],['what', 'is', 'this'],[123, 123, 123]], 
                           columns=['This', 'is', 'a Test'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([['bruh', 'this', 'is a gui'],[1235, 1235, 1235],[123, 123, 123]], 
                            columns=['This', 'is', 'a Test2'])

    if tableSelVar.get() == 'One':
        print('ONE')
        dfTbl.updateModel(TableModel(df1))
    elif tableSelVar.get() == 'Two':
        print('Two')
        dfTbl.updateModel(TableModel(df2))
    dfTbl.redraw()
```